# Python parsing tables with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, parsing, html-table, html-parsing

HTML-page structure:

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
           <th>Timestamp</th>
           <th>Call</th>
           <th>MHz</th>
           <th>SNR</th>
           <th>Drift</th>
           <th>Grid</th>
           <th>Pwr</th>
           <th>Reporter</th>
           <th>RGrid</th>
           <th>km</th> 
           <th>az</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td align="right">&nbsp;2019-12-10 14:02&nbsp;</td>
           <td align="left">&nbsp;DL1DUZ&nbsp;</td>
           <td align="right">&nbsp;10.140271&nbsp;</td>
           <td align="right">&nbsp;-26&nbsp;</td>
           <td align="right">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
           <td align="left">&nbsp;JO61tb&nbsp;</td>
           <td align="right">&nbsp;0.2&nbsp;</td>
           <td align="left">&nbsp;F4DWV&nbsp;</td>
           <td align="left">&nbsp;IN98bc&nbsp;</td>
           <td align="right">&nbsp;1162&nbsp;</td>
           <td align="right">&nbsp;260&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td align="right">&nbsp;2019-10-10 14:02&nbsp;</td>
           <td align="left">&nbsp;DL23UH&nbsp;</td>
           <td align="right">&nbsp;11.0021&nbsp;</td>
           <td align="right">&nbsp;-20&nbsp;</td>
           <td align="right">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
           <td align="left">&nbsp;JO61tb&nbsp;</td>
           <td align="right">&nbsp;0.2&nbsp;</td>
           <td align="left">&nbsp;F4DWV&nbsp;</td>
           <td align="left">&nbsp;IN98bc&nbsp;</td>
           <td align="right">&nbsp;1162&nbsp;</td>
           <td align="right">&nbsp;260&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and so on tr-td...
My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import csv

base_url = 'some_url'
session = requests.Session()
request = session.get(base_url)
val_th = []
val_td = []

if request.status_code == 200:
    soup = bs(request.content, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.findChildren('table')
    tr = soup.findChildren('tr')
    my_table = table[0]
    my_tr_th = tr[0]
    my_tr_td = tr[1]
    rows = my_table.findChildren('tr')
    row_th = my_tr_th.findChildren('th')
    row_td = my_tr_td.findChildren('td')
    for r_th in row_th:
       heading = r_th.text
       val_th.append(heading)
    for r_td in row_td:
        data = r_td.text
        val_td.append(data)
    with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
        a_pen = csv.writer(f)
        a_pen.writerow(val_th)
        a_pen.writerow(val_td)
```

1) I printed 1 line of `td`. How to make sure that all the lines of `td` on the page are displayed in csv?
2) `td` tags - many on the page.
3) If `my_tr_td = tr[1]` write as `my_tr_td = tr[1:50]` - it's mistake. 
How to write all data from `tr-td` lines to a csv file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: I get that; but what  exactly do you expect that file to contain?

Comment: output.csv. heading columns - tags <th>. rows - tags <td>

Comment: and further, There are many <tr><td> tags per page

Comment: If that's the case, can you edit your example to show what two sets of `tr/th` and `tr/td` look like?

Comment: No problem. I edited. Under the first tag <tr> always tags <th>, under two and more tags <tr> always tags <td>. http://wsprnet.org/drupal/wsprnet/spots - url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try it this way:

```
import lxml.html
import csv
import requests

url = "http://wsprnet.org/drupal/wsprnet/spots"
res = requests.get(url)

doc = lxml.html.fromstring(res.text)

cols = []
#first, we need to extract the column headers, stuck all the way at the top, with the first one in a particular location and format

cols.append(doc.xpath('//table/tr/node()/text()')[0])
for item in doc.xpath('//table/tr/th'):
    typ = str(type(item.getnext()))
    if not 'NoneType' in typ:        
        cols.append(item.getnext().text)
#now for the actual data
inf = []
for item in doc.xpath('//table//tr//td'):
    inf.append(item.text.replace('\\xa02', '').strip()) #text info needs to be cleaned

#this will take all the data and split it into rows for each column
rows = [inf[x:x+len(cols)] for x in range(0, len(inf), len(cols))]

#finally, write to file:
with open("output.csv", "w", newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(cols) 
    for l in rows:
        writer.writerow(l)
```

Comment: Thx, Jack. The code works. But the headers are written twice in the file. Like this: ['Timestamp', 'Call', 'MHz', 'SNR', 'Drift', 'Grid', 'Pwr', 'Reporter', 'RGrid', 'km', 'az'],Call,MHz,SNR,Drift,Grid,Pwr,Reporter,RGrid,km,az

Comment: @Outlaw - You're right! Typos... I changed the `cols.append()` statement in the edited version. Check again, please.

Comment: Sorry for worrying Jack. 
I need to pass the new page content to your function, but nothing works. How can this be implemented? After that -                                                            
btn_elem_upd = driver.find_element_by_id('edit-submit').click()
new_source = driver.page_source  
And then comes your function. I need "new_source" transfer to your function                                                                                  
url = "http://wsprnet.org/drupal/wsprnet/spots"
res = requests.get(url)
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(res.text)  How to do it?

Comment: @Outlaw - This is really a different question, and per SO policy (and also because it's a good idea) you should post it as a new question and, since it looks like a Selenium function, you should add the `Selenium` tag to your new question. I'll be happy to take a look then (and probably others as well...)

Comment: I'll create a new question. Thanks =)